# Ruby grouping elements

Tags: arrays, ruby, group-by, grouping

I have array:

```
a = [1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2]
```

And I want to group by values, but save it indexes, so result must be looks like this:

```
[[0, 2, 5], [1, 3], [4, 6]]
```

or hash

```
{1=>[0, 2, 5], 3=>[1, 3], 2=>[4, 6]}
```

Now I'm using pretty ugly and big code:

```
struc = Struct.new(:index, :value)
array = array.map.with_index{ |v, i| struc.new(i, v) }.group_by {|s| s[1]}.map { |h| h[1].map { |e| e[0]}}
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a hash with a default value to avoid iterating twice over the elements:

```
a = [1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2]

Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }.tap do |result|
  a.each_with_index { |i, n| result[i] << n }
end
#=> { 1 => [0, 2, 5], 3 => [1, 3], 2 => [4, 6] }
```

Comment: Good, or `a.each_with_index.with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }) { |(e,i),h| h[e] << i }`.

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland: TIL `with_object`, never looked into that method before.

Comment: You could also use [Enumerator#with_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index): `a.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }).with_index { |(e,h),i| h[e] << i }`. Note the different order of the block variables.  TIL TIL.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2]
a.each_with_index.group_by(&:first).values.map { |h| h.map &:last }
```

First we get an `Enumerator` in the form `[val, idx], ...` (`each_with_index`), then `group_by` the value (`first` value in pair), then take the index (`last` element) of each pair.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

- [Enumerable#each_with_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index)
- [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) and
- [Array#transpose](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose):

```
a = [1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2]

a.each_with_index.group_by(&:first).values.map { |b| b.transpose.last }
  #=> [[0, 2, 5], [1, 3], [4, 6]]
```